# Jupyter Notebook Export Fails with "nbconvert failed: Inkscape svg to pdf conversion failed"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, tex, inkscape, export-to-pdf

When I try to export a Jupyter notebook to pdf format, I receive the following error. `nbconvert failed: Inkscape svg to pdf conversion failed`. What's causing the error?

Answer (score 3):

This is currently an open issue it seems like: https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1325

But for me installing the nbconvert 6.0.0 version worked. In that version the code that **@Raoul** mentions has been modified:

```
pip install nbconvert==6.0.0
```

You also need to have Inkscape installed + make sure you can open inkscape from the terminal. In MacOS i had to do this:

```
ln -s /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape \
      /usr/local/bin/inkscape
```

I think where exactly the executable is depends on your version of inkscape. But if you have the latest version, it should be the same. Essentially typing `inkscape` in the terminal should open inkscape. That's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because export to pdf software isn't installed. Use the following commands to install the missing software. Commands shown are for debian distributions such as Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install inkscape pandoc texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-generic-recommended
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX and Anaconda distribution I was facing the same problem. I discovered that the problem is in the `/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/svg2pdf.py` file.

According to https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line
inside this file you have some lines  (which I commented out) which are obsolete and need to be replaced with the following.

```
class SVG2PDFPreprocessor(ConvertFiguresPreprocessor):
    """
    Converts all of the outputs in a notebook from SVG to PDF.
    """

    @default('from_format')
    def _from_format_default(self):
        return 'image/svg+xml'

    @default('to_format')
    def _to_format_default(self):
        return 'application/pdf'

    command = Unicode(
        help="""The command to use for converting SVG to PDF
        
        This string is a template, which will be formatted with the keys
        to_filename and from_filename.
        
        The conversion call must read the SVG from {from_filename},
        and write a PDF to {to_filename}.
        """).tag(config=True)

    # @default('command')
    # def _command_default(self):
    #     return self.inkscape + \
    #            ' --without-gui --export-pdf="{to_filename}" "{from_filename}"'

    @default('command')
    def _command_default(self):
        return self.inkscape + \
               ' --export-type="pdf" "{to_filename}" "{from_filename}"'
```

Also be sure that you have installed Inkscape:

- I have downloaded and installed the dmg
- I have also Symlink the binary:  `sudo ln -s /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape  /usr/local/bin`

And I have changed the path:

```
raoul@mbp-de-raoul ~ % export PATH=/Applications/anaconda3/bin:$PATH                                          
raoul@mbp-de-raoul ~ % jupyter --version 
jupyter core     : 4.6.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.6.0
ipython          : 7.12.0
ipykernel        : 5.1.4
jupyter client   : 5.3.4
jupyter lab      : 1.2.6
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.4
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

- And restarted the server

Now the export File > Download As > pdf is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps

1. pip install --upgrade nbconvert
2. sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic
3. pip install altair_saver

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on Ubuntu, and what fixed it for me was installing according their apt repo, as suggested on the [Inkscape Wiki](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Installing_Inkscape).

```
 sudo apt-get install inkscape
```