# How to solve 'nbconvert failed: Inkscape svg to pdf conversion failed` in JupyterLab

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, svg, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm using the command `%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'` to have high quality image. Then I `Export Notebook to PDF` and encounter the error

[image]

1. I install Inscape and added the line `c.SVG2PDFPreprocessor.inkscape = 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\bin\\inkscape.exe'` in the file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` as suggested [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/456#issuecomment-452833451).
2. I installed the `nbconvert 6.0.0` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63877093/7357673).

Sadly, both of them do not work. Could you please elaborate on how to solve this issue?

I use

- Windows 10 Pro 2004 build 19041.572.
- Anaconda3-2020.07
- Inkscape 1.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution for Windows 10.

1. Install `Inkscape` in a path that contains no space. In my case, it's `C:\Inkscape`.
2. Add the folder containing `inkscape.exe` into `environment variable`. In my case, this folder is `C:\Inkscape\bin`.

[image]

3. Update `nbconvert` with command `conda update nbconvert --yes`. In my case, I instead update all the packages by `conda update --all --yes`.

Comment: An alternative to reinstalling inkscape is to add a *symbolic link* with the symbolic link having a path that has no spaces.  For example the command 'mklink /D  c:\Inkscape "c:\Program Files\Inkscape"' creates a "fake" directory c:\inkscape that points to the "real" directory c:\Program Files\inkscape.  Now you just need to change the path to include the c:\inkscape\bin directory as per above.

Comment: Still a good answer in 2022. Just a note, though -- I thought that Windows 10/11 could update the `PATH` environment variable just by closing and reopening PowerShell. I was wrong. You need to completely log out/log in or restart.